# List in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been using PHP for a while now but had to move to ASP.NET MVC

I am trying to get an array like Below

```
Order[0]
      =>MaterialName="MName"
      =>MaterialType=1
      =>MaterialDescription="Description"
      =>Roles[0]
                 =>"Televsion"= "ABCTV"
                 =>"Radio"= "ABC Radio"
      =>Roles[1]
                 =>"Televsion"= "DEFTV"
                 =>"Radio"= "DEF Radio"

Order[1]
      =>MaterialName="MName"
      =>MaterialType=1
      =>MaterialDescription="Description"
      =>Roles[0]
                 =>"Televsion"= "ABCTV"
                 =>"Radio"= "ABC Radio"
      =>Roles[1]
                 =>"Televsion"= "DEFTV"
                 =>"Radio"= "DEF Radio"
```

I could generate this in PHP by making the first array and append others afterwards.

And Also loop through to get the values out of it.

I want to get this done in ASP.NET MVC but to no avail.

Arrays dont allow names and dictionary cannot be appended.

Comment: try using the `List`.....

Comment: That is not a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: In what context are you creating this? What does it have to do with mvc? Are you wanting to generate json to post back to a controller method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you need a model.

In your case, it'd look like this

```
public class Order 
{
  public string MaterialName { get; set; }
  public int MaterialType { get; set; } // consider making this an Enum
  public string MaterialDescription { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can define your collection:

```
var orders = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Order>{
 new Order 
    {
    MaterialName = "MName", 
    MaterialType = 1,
    MaterialDescription = "Description",
    Roles = new Dictionary<string, string> 
        {
            {"Television", "ABCTV"},
            {"Radio", "ABCDEF RadioTV"},
        }
    },
     new Order 
    {
    MaterialName = "MName", 
    MaterialType = 1,
    MaterialDescription = "Description",
    Roles = new Dictionary<string, string> 
        {
            {"Television", "ABCTV"},
            {"Radio", "ABCDEF RadioTV"},
        }
    }
};
```

EDIT: It may also be that your `Roles` is an array of Dictionary, in which case we can do this:

```
public class Order 
{
  public string MaterialName { get; set; }
  public int MaterialType { get; set; } // consider making this an Enum
  public string MaterialDescription { get; set; }
  public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can define your collection:

```
var orders = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Order>{
 new Order 
    {
    MaterialName = "MName", 
    MaterialType = 1,
    MaterialDescription = "Description",
    Roles = new List<Dictionary<string, string>> {
    new Dictionary<string, string> 
        {
            {"Television", "ABCTV"},
            {"Radio", "ABCDEF RadioTV"},
        },
    new Dictionary<string, string> 
        {
            {"Television", "ABCTV"},
            {"Radio", "ABCDEF RadioTV"},
        }
    },
    new Order 
    {
    MaterialName = "MName", 
    MaterialType = 1,
    MaterialDescription = "Description",
    Roles = new List<Dictionary<string, string>> {
    new Dictionary<string, string> 
        {
            {"Television", "ABCTV"},
            {"Radio", "ABCDEF RadioTV"},
        },
    new Dictionary<string, string> 
        {
            {"Television", "ABCTV"},
            {"Radio", "ABCDEF RadioTV"},
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: Roles must be someting else- maybe another list of class `Role` wich contains field  `Televsion` and `Radio`

Comment: Why do they `must` be something else? The way the object is transcribed, it is a dictionary. Now it may be a `JRaw` because it is preserialized, for example, or string or something, but the way the OP posted their listing, there is a clear formatting difference between properties and keys inside `Roles`

Comment: `Roles[0]` and `Roles[1]` didn't say anything? It's naturally an array of objects. Value from Roles must be retrived by index + key. So it is not a Dictionary, which provide only key different values.

Comment: @zaitsman, it works. But how can i append to an existing orders. For instance the order comes one at a time, Passed into the method and i get the previous value in the order and append the new one to it.

Also can the order be converted to string and back to List

Comment: `orders` variable i showed is a `List<>`, thus it has a `.Add()` method. So you can just do `orders.Add(new Order());` anywhere you want